# as many items as I am adding to my cart,that many times it shows Total price layout

Tags: android-studio

```
as many items as I am adding to my cart,that many times it shows Total price layout    

if (cartList.size() != 0) {
   cartItemModelList.add(new CartItemModel(CartItemModel.TOTAL_AMOUNT));
   LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) cartTotalAmount.getParent().getParent();
   parent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       }
```

[please see total amount layout is showing 2-3 times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkfH0.jpg)

Comment: Set a breakpoint in this part of the code and check how often it is called.

Comment: I set a breakpoint but it does not work for me because i not able to set the logic and  dont understandd it @derpirscher